# Por qué el operador in da distintos resultados al buscar una cadena vacía

Tags: python

¿Por qué pasa esto en python?

```
"" in ("A")

True

"" in ("A","B","C")

False
```

Gracias.

Comment: El primero NO es una tupla, si no una cadena rodeada de parentesis. El in busca la cadena vacía en "A" y, por supuesto, una cadena vacía es subcadena de cualquier cadena.

Comment: El segundo caso es una tupla de cadenas y se usa la operación de igualdad en cada una de ellas para saber si "" está en la tupla. Y claro, "A" no es igual a "".

Answer (score 4):

Aunque las expresiones lucen más o menos equivalentes, no lo son.

Veamos, primero, el operador `in` es un [*membership operator*](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp), cuyo comportamiento depende del tipo de datos de los operandos.

## Membership de strings

En el primer caso, el segundo operando es una cadena, un string (el hecho de estar entre paréntesis no cambia este hecho), como podemos comprobar al hacer:

```
print(type(("A")))
```

lo que devuelve:

```
<class 'str'>
```

En el caso de cadenas, encontramos [esto](https://www.oraask.com/wiki/python-string-membership):

> An “in” operator keyword returns True. If the given element / entire substring is present in the given string, otherwise it returns False.

Mi traducción libre:

> El operador "in" devuelve True si el elemento dado o la subcadena completa está presente en la cadena dada, de lo contrario devuelve False.

Según podemos ver, una cadena vacía siempre va a estar en cualquier otra cadena, por ejemplo:

```
print("" in ("A"))
print("" in "hola")
print("" in "")
```

Nos devuelve

```
True
True
True
```

Como se ha dicho, podemos utilizar el operador `in` para determinar si una subcadena es parte de un string (sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas), puedes probar:

```
print("ola" in "hola")
print("O" in "hola")
```

## Membership de tuplas

En el segundo caso, el segundo operando es una tupla, como podemos comprobar al hacer:

```
print(type(("A","B","C")))
```

lo que devuelve:

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

En ese caso, encontramos esto sobre [membresía de tuplas](https://www.oraask.com/wiki/python-tuple-membership):

> Python tuple membership operators (‘in’ & ‘not in’) is used to check whether the value is a part of given tuple or not.

Mi traducción libre:

> Los operadores de membresía de tupla de Python ('in' y 'not in') se usan para verificar si un valor dado forma parte de una tupla o no.

De esta manera, encontramos que:

```
print("" in ("A","B","C"))
print("A" in ("A","B","C"))
print("C" in ("A","B","C"))
print("X" in ("A","B","C"))
```

Nos devuelve:

```
False
True
True
False
```